# Difference between プランター and ウィンドウボックス

Tags: word-choice

I have a long rectangular plastic pot filled with earth that I hang on my balcony rail to grow small vegetables, and I am not sure whether I should call it プランター or ウィンドウボックス.

**QUESTION**: What is the fundamental difference between プランター and ウィンドウボックス?

According to Wikipedia:

> [ウィンドウボックス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9)、ウインドウボックス（英語: windowbox, window box）とは、ガーデニング・園芸で植物を育てるために、窓の外側（あるいは内側）に置かれる容器（コンテナ）や、その下の壁面で支えるブラケット（棚受け）のこと。
>
> [プランター](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC)（planter）は装飾用の草花を植えたり活けるための鉢や箱の事。 イギリスやアメリカでは、planter と flower pot(植木鉢) をほとんど同義に使い、あまり区別をしない。また花器、花瓶をも planter と呼ぶ場合も少なくない。

[image: Window Box][image: プランター http://blog.goo.ne.jp/newvegeculture/e/3ef2cebd3b41661ae6f80ce029002303]

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter Japanese words in katagana, it always helps to know its original language. In this case, プランター means "planter", and ウィンドウボックス means "window box".

If you take a look at Google Image search reasults of these two words, you will find that window boxes are always placed on edges of windows, while planters can be placed on the ground.

**Window Boxes**
[image: Window Boxes]

**Planters**
[image: Planters]

Comment: So your conclusion is that both words apply to my case, but ウィンドウボックス is more specific, right? The advertisement on the left in my question shows a ウィンドウボックス without any hanging hooks, so I guess the word is more about the object's usage than about the object's intrinsic features.

Comment: But if you googled images for 「窓　プランター」: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E7%AA%93%E3%80%80%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbmtLQrd7MAhWMmZQKHeqFBdAQsAQIPw

Comment: @Nicolas: Yes, "window box" is more suitable in your case.